# How to handle undefined as API response when using spread operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using react and context: When I fetch items and there is no data, I send null. null becomes undefined (within res.send). In my reducer, I use spread operator when new items are being added. That results in an err as I'm trying to spread undefined (when there is no items yet and later added its first undefined).

What is good practice and what should I do in this case to change undefined into an empty array or so? Thank you

```js
const initialState = {
  isFetchingItems: null,
  items: [],
  fetchErrorMessage: null
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_ITEMS':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      }
    case 'FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload.messages,
        isFetching: false
      }
    case 'FETCH_ITEMS_ERROR':
      return {
        ...state,
        fetchErrorMessage: action.payload,
        isFetching: false
      }
    case 'ADD_ITEMS_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [action.payload, ...state.items] // here the err comes from as its like [action.payload, ...undefined]
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My action:

```js
const fetchItems = async() => {
  dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ITEMS' })
  try {
    let items = await API.fetchItems();
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_Items_SUCCESS', payload: items })
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ITEMS_ERROR', payload: error.message })
  }
};

const fetchItems = async() => {
  // ...
  dispatch({ type: 'ADD_ITEMS_SUCCESS', payload: items })
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) for simple and concise fallback behavior:

```
[action.payload, ...(state.items ?? [])]
```

If `state.items` is `null` or `undefined`, `[]` will be used instead of `state.items`. Otherwise, it's going to use `state.items`.

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

The issue is not maintaining a state invariant, the `items` state should preferably *always* be an array type. The issue is caused by the `FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS` action receiving a null/undefined messages property, and exposed when the `ADD_ITEMS_SUCCESS` action is attempting to prepend an item to the `state.items` array.

```
const initialState = {
  isFetchingItems: null,
  items: [],
  fetchErrorMessage: null
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_ITEMS':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      }
    case 'FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload.messages, // <-- issue is caused here
        isFetching: false
      }
    case 'FETCH_ITEMS_ERROR':
      return {
        ...state,
        fetchErrorMessage: action.payload,
        isFetching: false
      }
    case 'ADD_ITEMS_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [action.payload, ...state.items] // <-- exposed here when undefined
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

## Solution

Maintain the `state.items` invariant as an array. If the `payload.messages` property is falsey then provide a valid fallback value of an empty array.

```
const initialState = {
  isFetchingItems: null,
  items: [],
  fetchErrorMessage: null
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_ITEMS':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      }
    case 'FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload.messages ?? [], // <-- provide fallback
        isFetching: false
      }
    case 'FETCH_ITEMS_ERROR':
      return {
        ...state,
        fetchErrorMessage: action.payload,
        isFetching: false
      }
    case 'ADD_ITEMS_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [action.payload, ...state.items] // <-- now a safe operation
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

An optimization here might be to ***not*** dispatch the `FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS` action if there were no fetched items.

Example:

```
const fetchItems = async() => {
  dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ITEMS' });
  try {
    const items = await API.fetchItems();

    if (items?.messages) {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_Items_SUCCESS', payload: items });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ITEMS_ERROR', payload: error.message });
  }
};
```